# Framer Motion dynamic variants don't work when modifying initial properties

Tags: reactjs, animation, css-animations, framer-motion

According to the docs I can make variant properties dynamic: https://www.framer.com/docs/animation/##dynamic-variants.

But this doesn't work when I try to make the `initial` properties dynamic.

For example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { motion, useAnimation } from "framer-motion";

//make div appear from either bottom or right, depending on "origin" custom prop
const variant = {
  hidden: (origin) =>
    origin === "bottom"
      ? { x: 0, y: 200, opacity: 0 }
      : { x: 200, y: 0, opacity: 0 },
  visible: { x: 0, y: 0, opacity: 1, transition: { duration: 1 } },
};

function App() {
  const [origin, setOrigin] = useState("bottom");
  const controls = useAnimation();

  //after 2 secs make origin "right"
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setOrigin("right");
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  //after 4 secs start the animation
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      controls.start("visible");
    }, 4000);
  }, [controls]);

  return (
    <motion.div
      style={{ width: 100, height: 50, background: "red" }}
      variants={variant}
      initial="hidden"
      animate={controls}
      custom={origin}
    />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here I made a dynamic variant to make a div appear from either the right or bottom, which I can control from a `custom` prop. Initially this `custom` prop is set to "bottom". After 2 secs, this is changed to "right". When I start the animation after 4 secs, I expect the div to appear from the right but it still appears from the bottom:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This is because the component is already rendered and is still the same component even if the `origin` prop being passed to the component has changed.

You can do two things:

1. Use a `isVisible` state variable where the `render` method will observe for changes and render the component when it becomes `true`.

```js
function App() {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);

  ...

  //after 4 secs start the animation
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIsVisible(true);
      controls.start("visible");
    }, 4000);
  }, [controls]);

  return (
    isVisible && (
      <motion.div
        ...
      />
    )
  );
}
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-2-layout-animations-forked-eofm0?file=/src/App.js)

2. Add a `key` prop to the component with the origin value so that when the value changes, React will re-render the component.

```js
function App() {
  ...

  return (
    <motion.div
      key={origin}
      ...
    />
  );
}
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-2-layout-animations-forked-oz59g?file=/src/App.js)

2nd option may be your preferred choice if you need to toggle between the `origin`.

Comment: great username and great answer. Setting the key prop so that the component re-renders is what's needed to make the framer motion accept dynamic props.